# mongo-cxx-driver, where are the implementations of bson_value::view::get_string() and document::element::get_string()?

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

I did a `grep` and only see `... get_string const;` declarations for both functions, no actual implementation  in any hpp or cpp files in github.com/mongo-cxx-driver/src. Did anyone know where they live?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to see the implementation?

Comment: I'm still learning C++ so I guess it's also an out of curiosity thing?

Comment: You can check their repository. The repository contains all the needed sources. This is not the site to ask such questions.

Comment: I did, downloaded their repo and did a grep, nothing turned up. Hence asking here, since there's likely something I do not know.

Comment: *”and did a grep”* how will you know what’s going on with a grep?

Comment: never mind, found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done via name decoration/mangling, hence `grep` for `get_string` in the code source did not return any function definition.

```
//bsoncxx/v_noabi/bsoncxx/document/element.cpp
#define BSONCXX_ENUM(name, val) \
    types::b_##name element::get_##name() const { \
    ...
```

and

```
//bsoncxx/v_noabi/bsoncxx/enums/type.hpp
BSONCXX_ENUM(string, 0x02)
```